# Weighted random sampling without replacement, with defined probabilities.

Tags: statistics

Let's define output of such sampling like this:

Output: A weighted random sample of size m. The probability of each item to be
included in the random sample is proportional to its relative weight.

My question is why is it impossible to sample with such probabilities if a relative weight of one element is more than $\frac{1}{m}$.

PS: More details can be found here:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0256.pdf - Definition 2 in 2nd chapter. But I can't understand an explanation there.